Clarification regarding the meaning of Universal Time UT1
I've been reading the book "From Sundials to Atomic Clocks: Understanding Time and Frequency" by James Jespersen and Jane Fitz-Randolph which is available at https://www.nist.gov/system/files/documents/pml/general/1796.pdf. On page 107, it says

"UT1 is UT0 corrected for the polar motion of the Earth".

I'm having a little bit of difficulty in understanding this. I have looked at other books and articles on the web but they all say pretty much the same thing. My question is this: Is it accurate to say that Universal Time UT1 at any instant is the time that would exist at that instant if there were no polar motion?

From A brief history of time scales The modern techniques for measuring earth orientation (which became the prevalent means of observation by the 1980s) simultaneously produce UT1 and polar motion directly, so UT0 is effectively not used anymore.

@PM2Ring Yes, but that doesn't answer my question. If we take UT0 to be as it was defined before it fell into disuse, is my understanding of UT1 correct?

UT0 assumes there is no polar motion, UT1 takes polar motion into account. If there were no polar motion then UT0 and UT1 would be identical.

UT0 and UT1 measure time in reference to the day: the period of time it takes for the planet to rotate.  UT (now called UT0) was a "mean" solar time, meaning it was an averaging of seasonal effects.  As we gathered more and more precise ways of measuring, it became clear that a motion of the earth, which we now call polar motion, was not being accounted for in the UT calculations.  This means UT times were not the best estimator of where your telescope was pointing at any time.  To solve this, they renamed UT UT0, and developed UT1 which accounts for this polar motion.  There is also a UT2, but it fell out of favor as the benefits of UT2 were similar to those of UTC, and UTC had other benefits that made it preferable.

I'm a little confused based on what you've said and what @PM2Ring said in the comment above. Since UT0 is determined from direct observations of the daily motion of stars, wouldn't the effects of polar motion be included in those observations?

The ut0 formulae did not account for the effect.  Using a bit of hyperbole to demonstrate, it would be like making a linear fit of 1,4,9,16,25... You can fit it, but it doesn't capture the data very well unless you have a quadratic term in your estimator.

@russell Polar motion means that you don't know exactly where the pole is relative to  your observatory, so your telescope isn't exactly pointing in the direction that you think its pointing. The polar motion effectively adds a small error term to the latitude and longitude of your observatory.

(cont) You can measure your latitude by determining the altitude of the celestial pole. But that takes time, and it's tricky to get it to high precision due to atmospheric refraction. But to determine your longitude you need to know the time, so you get a circular reference problem when your main task is to determine the time. ;)

@Cort I mostly agree with your answer, but I'm not sure I like the wording of the final part. UTC tracks TAI, except that it's adjusted with leapseconds so that DUT1 = UT1 - UTC stays in the range  −0.9 s < DUT1 < +0.9 s.

@PM2Ring I think I understand it now. Thank you! Looks like I had gotten it backwards earlier.

@russell No worries. It's a confusing topic! I find Steve Allen's articles on the Lick Observatory site helpful, especially A Brief History of Time Scales, but other pages are useful too, eg https://www.ucolick.org/~sla/leapsecs/dutc.html

@PM2Ring It's fair to disagree with that detail of UTC vs UT2.  What I was speaking to was that people found UTC to be more useful than UT2, so UT2 fell by the wayside in practical use.  I didn't cite my sources there, but I was paraphrasing wikipedia "UT0 and UT2 soon became irrelevant due to the introduction of Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)."  UT2 was always intended for civil use, but the civil community eventually adopted UTC instead.

Ah, ok. It would never have been practically possible to use UT0, UT1, or UT2 directly as civil time. But you could regularly reset an official clock to one of those timescales. By the early 1960s, most time services were using quartz clocks, but some were still using pendulums. These clocks were adjusted as necessary to the time supplied by astronomers, but those procedures varied, and are not always well-documented.

From Brief History: The original goal of what was informally called UTC was for radio broadcasts around the world to be synchronized with each other while providing a time which matched the expected value of UT2 as closely as could be predicted in advance. [...] The last time that everyone involved in the definition of UTC agreed on the concepts was 1964, the same year that the term UTC first appeared in print. [...] A flame war erupts almost every time any organization starts a discussion about the technical details of UTC.
